# Unable to resolve "react-redux" from "App.js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Working on Windows, ran "npm install --save redux" and "npm install --save react-redux" then linked them. Expo shows error "Unable to resolve "react-redux" from "App.js"" when trying to build the JavaScript bundle on the Android emulator. My package.json currently looks like this:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.3.4",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[image: Emulator error shows:]

Any tips on how I might be able to solve? I usually work on Mac and this is the first time I'm seeing these issues.

EDIT: Added App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Picker, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import ChargingInfo from './ChargingInfo';
import VehicleSelect from './VehicleSelect';
import ChargingProfile from './ChargingProfile';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: VehicleSelect},
  ChargingInfo: {screen: ChargingInfo},
  ChargingProfile: {screen: ChargingProfile}
});

// const initialState = {

// }

// const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

// }

// const store = createStore(reducer)

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

// export default class App extends React.Component {
//   render() {
//     return (
//       <Provider store={store}>
//         <AppNavigator />
//       </Provider>
//     );
//   }
// }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});
```

Comment: Try shutting the bundled down. Reinstall your node modules. Then try `expo start -c` to restart expo with clearing the cache.

Comment: tried, no luck. tried also deleting it manually from the nodes_modules folder and then reinstall. still same issues

Comment: Package.json shows that react-redux has been installed. Can you share the App.js?

Comment: @fsociety added

Comment: @rrain I've faced similar issues with CRNA in the past but never with Expo. I suggest you create a new project, reinstall dependencies, and copy the source code to the new project.